# Active Directory vs SQL Server for storing images

Tags: c#, sql-server, active-directory

I am about to add functionality to our web application for users to upload there pictures, I have three choices,

1. SQL Server database
2. File System (ruled out)
3. Active Directory photo property

I already ruled out file system as we don't want to backup file system, now I need to choose between AD and DB, there's tons of material for DB vs file system but nothing much for SQL Server database vs Active Directory. Which one will be more performant and recommended way of moving forward ?

Comment: AD has a clear advantage that if you upload the user's photo there, it will be available everywhere in your system - all your system admin tools etc. Storing it in a SQL Server database probably makes it accessible only in the application that uses this one SQL Server database.

Comment: @marc_s that makes perfect sense, but isn't querying AD slow ? specially when you need full name of a user and only thing you stored in your SQL database is your userSID (our software arch is very poorly desiged), so in case of 1000 records from db, I will have to query AD 1000 times just to get user's details, just figured out a better way querying AD from SQL but I am not sure if it will be any faster...

Comment: Well, there's pro and cons, good and bad for every solution - in the end, it always comes down to which is the most pressing need for you. You haven't provided quite enough information to make that call - ***YOU*** know what your ultimate needs are therefore you're the best one to figure it out ...